# WARNING: Unsupported Kotlin plugin version

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, kotlin-dsl

The `embedded-kotlin` and `kotlin-dsl` plugins rely on features of Kotlin `1.4.31` that might work differently than in the requested version `1.5.21`

How to set `embedded-kotlin` and `kotlin-dsl` to version 1.5.21 ?